# Simple first order logic satisfy for every formula

Tags: logic

I'm studing logic as autodidact and i stucking on this sentence :

show that :

if for every model $M$, $M \vDash \lnot \Phi$ then, for every $\Phi$, $\Phi \vDash \Psi$.

What is the correct way for this kind of problem?

Thank you so much

Comment: I'm in doubt about the little "-" sign ... Is it a "negation" ? If so, the statement must be : if for every model $\mathcal M$, $\mathcal M \vDash \lnot \Phi$, then for every $\Psi$, $\Phi \vDash \Psi$ ... Is it right ?

Comment: you are right Mauro, is a negation

Comment: Assuming my reading correct, the above problem means : we have a formula $\Phi$ such that its negation ($\lnot \Phi$) is *true* in every model. If $\lnot \Phi$ is *true* in every model, then $\Phi$ is *false* in every model, i.e. for **no** model $\mathcal M$, $\Phi$ is true in $\mathcal M$. Now the relation of *logical consequence* between sentences says that : $\Phi \vDash \Psi$ iff every model of $\Phi$ is also a model of $\Psi$. But $\Phi$ has no models; so the last condition is vacuosly satisfied for every $\Psi$.

Comment: so the Ø ⊨ Ψ is vacuosly satisfied for every Ψ ?

Answer (score 1):

The above symbol means : we have a formula $\Phi$ such that its negation ($\lnot \Phi$) is true in every model.

If $\lnot \Phi$ is true in every model, then $\Phi$ is false in every model, i.e. for no model $\mathcal M$, $\Phi$ is true in $\mathcal M$.

Now the relation of logical consequence between sentences says that :

> $\Phi \vDash \Psi$ iff every model of $\Phi$ is also a model of $\Psi$.

But $\Phi$ has no models; so the last condition is vacuosly satisfied for every $\Psi$.

This case is different from $\emptyset \vDash \Psi$ (also abbreviated as $\vDash \Psi$), which means "$\Psi$ is valid" (or, in propositional logic: is a tautology).

This is the case when $\Gamma = \emptyset$; in this case it is vacuously true that any interpretation satisfies every member of $\emptyset$ (How could this fail? Only if there was some unsatisfied member in it: but we have no sentences into $\emptyset$.)

Hence we have : $\emptyset \vDash \Psi$ iff every interpretation satisfies $\Psi$, and this is the definition of *valid* formula (i.e."logical truth").